# How to pass multidimensional data from one page to another using forms and PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to pass multiple values pertaining to each item from one page to another using a form as a multidimensional array. It is for a shopping cart of sorts. I am passing variables through hidden values using forms. The values of these variables are entered using echo. The variable values are in PHP. I need to use these value on another PHP page.

I need to get this data in page 2 in the form of a table from which I can call the data using orderitem['quantity'] etc. But no matter what I tried I keep getting errors. Please help.

Page 1:

```
<input type="hidden" name="orderitem[item][]" value="<?php echo $order_cart_item; ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="orderitem[quantity][]" value="<?php echo $order_cart[$i]['item_q']; ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="orderitem[price][]" value="<?php echo $row['item_price'];?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="orderitem[total][]" value="<?php echo $row['item_price']*$order_cart[$i]['item_q'];?>">
         <textarea name="orderitem[comments][]" rows="3" cols="35" placeholder="Please mention special requests if you have any. (Example: Happy Birthday Jerry!)"></textarea>
```

Page 2:

```
 if(($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"))
 {


    $result = $_GET['orderitem'];
    echo "Product ID\tQuantity\tAmount\tTotal\t";
    echo "\n", $result["itemcode"], "\t\t", $result["quantity"], "\t\t",$result["price"], "\t\t", $result["total"];
}
var_dump($_GET['orderitem']);}
```

Result of Var Dump:

```
Arrayarray(5) { ["item"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "CC9011" [1]=> string(6) "CCC675" } ["quantity"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(1) "2" } ["price"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "900" [1]=> string(2) "60" } ["total"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "3600" [1]=> string(3) "120" } ["comments"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } }
```

The Output in Page 2:

```
Product ID  Quantity    Amount  Total   
Notice: Undefined index: itemcode in /opt/lampp/htdocs/momsoven/orderconfirmation.php on line 96

Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/momsoven/orderconfirmation.php on line 96
Array   
Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/momsoven/orderconfirmation.php on line 96
Array   
Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/momsoven/orderconfirmation.php on line 96
Arrayarray(5) { ["item"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "CC9011" [1]=> string(6) "CCC675" } ["quantity"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(1) "2" } ["price"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "900" [1]=> string(2) "60" } ["total"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "3600" [1]=> string(3) "120" } ["comments"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Comment: I tried  print_r($_POST['orderitem']); and i got output as Array ( [item] => CC9011 [quantity] => 2 [price] => 900 [total] => 1800 [comments] => ).     item is only one colum of the array. I need all colums to be accessible, item,price,total,quantity,comments. Please check the html code I wrote in page 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In foreach loop $var is value of array. You have no need to use foreach loop.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $result = $_POST['orderitem'];
    echo "Product ID\tQuantity\tAmount\tTotal\t";
    echo "\n", $result["item"], "\t\t", $result["quantity"], "\t\t",$result["price"], "\t\t", $result["total"];
}
?>
```

If same input fields have multiple record, Add the form Input elements as an array.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$result = $_POST['orderitem'];
echo "Product ID\tQuantity\tAmount\tTotal\t";

    for($i=0 ; $i<count($result['quantity']); $i++){
        echo "\n", $result["item"][$i], "\t\t", $result["quantity"][$i], "\t\t",$result["price"][$i], "\t\t", $result["total"][$i];
    }
 }

?>


<form name="test" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="orderitem[item][]" value="order_cart_items">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderitem[quantity][]" value="item_q">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderitem[price][]" value="item_price">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderitem[total][]" value="item_price">
    <textarea name="orderitem[comments][]" rows="3" cols="35" placeholder="Please mention special requests if you have any. (Example: Happy Birthday Jerry!)"></textarea>


    <input type="hidden" name="orderitem[item][]" value="order_cart_items">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderitem[quantity][]" value="item_q">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderitem[price][]" value="item_price">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderitem[total][]" value="item_price">
    <textarea name="orderitem[comments][]" rows="3" cols="35" placeholder="Please mention special requests if you have any. (Example: Happy Birthday Jerry!)"></textarea>



    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```